# Is there a way to limit the number of restarts of pod?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-deployment, livenessprobe

I have implemented liveness probe in my kubernetes deployment file. as of now it attempts restart infinite number of times.
Is there a way to limit this  number of restart attempts?

Comment: There is an option restartPolicy: Never to not restart Pod. As I know there aren't other options for liveness/readiness probes. You can check every option by issuing kubectl explain pod --recursive | less

Comment: After the first couple of restarts there will be a delay between them (if you see a pod in CrashLoopBackOff state, Kubernetes is waiting for a while before restarting it again) but I believe it will keep retrying forever.